# Collapse accordion on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, collapsable

I am using a worpdress theme that has an accordion included. I need to be able to close the accordion on click. Below is the code from the accordion.js file included with the theme. Can you please advise?

```
( function( $ ){

$( document ).ready( function () {

        // Expand/Collapse on click
        $( '.accordion-container' ).on( 'click keydown', '.accordion-section-title', function( e ) {
            if ( e.type === 'keydown' && 13 !== e.which ) // "return" key
                    return;
            e.preventDefault(); // Keep this AFTER the key filter above

            accordionSwitch( $( this ) );
        });

        // Re-initialize accordion when screen options are toggled
        $( '.hide-postbox-tog' ).click( function () {
            accordionInit();
        });

    });

    var accordionOptions = $( '.accordion-container li.accordion-section' ),
        sectionContent   = $( '.accordion-section-content' );

    function accordionInit () {
        // Rounded corners
        accordionOptions.removeClass( 'top bottom' );
        accordionOptions.filter( ':visible' ).first().addClass( 'top' );
        accordionOptions.filter( ':visible' ).last().addClass( 'bottom' ).find( sectionContent ).addClass( 'bottom' );
    }

    function accordionSwitch ( el ) {
        var section = el.closest( '.accordion-section' ),
            siblings = section.closest( '.accordion-container' ).find( '.open' ),
            content = section.find( sectionContent );

        if ( section.hasClass( 'cannot-expand' ) )
            return;

        if ( section.hasClass( 'open' ) ) {
            section.toggleClass( 'open' );
            content.toggle( true ).slideToggle( 150 );
        } else {
            siblings.removeClass( 'open' );
            siblings.find( sectionContent ).show().slideUp( 150 );
            content.toggle( false ).slideToggle( 150 );
            section.toggleClass( 'open' );
        }

        accordionInit();
    }

    // Initialize the accordion (currently just corner fixes)
    accordionInit();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You can save yourself the javascript & jquery trouble and use CSS here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/accordions/. Its a great article, maybe you can incorporate it with our jquery

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console? More detail would be helpful to providing you answers to your question.